# Reorganize numbers/words inside punctuations

Tags: notepad++

I have a text that is organized like this using punctuation “`|`” from the closest example:

```
hello: one|three|two|four|
```

or sometimes the form comes in numbers, not letters

```
hello: 1|3|2|4|
```

Is there a possibility to move words or numbers from the second position to the third or vice versa?

To became like this (respectively):

```
hello: one|**two**|**three**|four|
hello: 1|**2**|**3**|4|
```

I used “**” to mark the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the following regular expression:

```
hello: +(?:\w+\|){N}\K(\w+)\|(\w+)
```

and replace with

```
$2|$1
```

where `N` is the number of words preceding the first one that you want to swap. In your example, N=1.

Demo screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Be sure to have checked the "Regular expression" mode.

Answer (score 0):

This time an alternative with long code, which may work
In most editors that support Regular Expression ...
 `Updated`

Find: `^(hello: \w+\|)(\w+\|)(\w+\|)`
Replace All: `$1$3$2`

[image]

Comment: I feel sure that the question also wants to handle and rearrange inputs like `Apples|Cherries|Bananas|Dates` or like `9905|9907|9906|0098`.

Comment: @AdrianHHH ✔ Check the updates,  this for sure shortened my code...